# Angular 9 - NativeScript - The target entry-point "side-drawer-directives" has missing dependencies: - ./

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have upgraded an Angular library to Angular 9. However when I attempt to use that library nativescript-ui-sidedrawer in another Angular 9 project I get an error like this:

ERROR in The target entry-point "side-drawer-directives" has missing dependencies:
 - ./..

Package.json:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.NativescriptChallenge",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "ngcc": "ngcc --properties es2015 module main --first-only",
    "postinstall": "npm run ngcc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~9.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^8.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^1.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~9.1.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^9.1.7",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.5.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "~6.5.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "3153594d609d66fab71745c881d617ac1328ea1b",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `ngcc.config.js` sample provided here: 
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/wiki/Updating-and-developing-for-@nativescript-angular-v9-with-Ivy-or-without#problem-2

In short, try updating your ngcc.config.js to this, then clean and re-run again:

```
module.exports = {
  "packages": {
    "@nativescript/angular": {
      entryPoints: {
        ".": {
          override: {
            main: "./index.js",
            typings: "./index.d.ts",
          },
          ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
        }
      },
      ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
        /zone.js\//,
        /tns-core-modules\//,
        /@nativescript\/core\//
      ]
    },
    "nativescript-datetimepicker": {
      entryPoints: {
        ".": {
          override: {
            main: "./index.js",
            typings: "./index.d.ts",
          },
          ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
        },
        "angular": {
          override: {
            main: "./index.js",
            typings: "./index.d.ts",
          },
          ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
        }
      },
      ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
        /tns-core-modules\//,
        /@nativescript\/core\//,
        /@nativescript\/angular\//
      ]
    },
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": {
      entryPoints: {
        "angular": {
          override: {
            main: "./side-drawer-directives.js",
            typings: "./side-drawer-directives.d.ts",
          },
          ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
        }
      },
      ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
        /tns-core-modules\//,
        /@nativescript\/core\//,
        /@nativescript\/angular\//
      ]
    },
    "nativescript-ui-listview": {
      entryPoints: {
        "angular": {
          override: {
            main: "./listview-directives.js",
            typings: "./listview-directives.d.ts",
          },
          ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
        }
      },
      ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
        /tns-core-modules\//,
        /@nativescript\/core\//,
        /@nativescript\/angular\//
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly in Android. 

However now I recieve the following error in iOS

JavaScript error:
file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/tab-view/tab-view.ios.js:416:23: JS ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'tabBar.items.count')

Any Idea how to solve it? Thank you